# Problem in Installing Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, installation

I try to install Wordpress in a Windows Client with `WebPI` which provided by Microsoft.

Everything installed in my client and finally I saw successful message. with a lunch application link. When I click on it I see following error.

```
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.
```

How Can I resolve this issue

I asked this at [ServerFault Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/149978/problem-in-installing-wordpress)

Comment: ...install the MySQL extension? This isn't exactly a programming question. Maybe if you asked in serverfault or a WebPI related forum?

Comment: If you are doing this just to test wordpress out, or you don't have the necessity to use IIS or Microsoft tools, I'd recommend to switch to  XAMPP (for Windows) instead. You'll get a standard Apache and mysql up in minutes...

Comment: @Manos @Palantir - I Installed it to add some feature to out Wordpress template and etc. `WebPI` is really awesome and It is really easy to use (even easier than xampp ). as I told you everything done successfully and I don't know whats the matter with this message. so Can you please show me a way to resolve this issue, because I don't want to install apache. I have lots of Aspx applications which has to be run. thank you in advance.

Comment: This is nothing to do with WordPress - PHP has not been compiled with or configured to load the MySQL extension. You're much better off asking this @ serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your php.ini file for the correct paths. If you don't have access to it, ask your web host: https://serverfault.com/search?q=missing+mysql+extension

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good utility that can detect problems with your PHP installation as well as fix them for you: [PHP Manager 1.1](http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2010/12/10/php-manager-1-1-available-in-web-pi.aspx). You can also install it with Web PI (the link to installation is in the article)